# Excel sum values based on group defined in another table

Tags: excel

I'm fairly new to Excel and was wondering if someone could assist me with this problem.

I want to sum all the values in E1:E6 for the two groups of animals A and B. The groups the animals belong to are defined in a separate table A1:B6. Essentially I have been trying to produce a formula using a combination of SUMIF and VLOOKUP statements to achieve the values in orange. Cell E9 for example is the sum of all animals in group A (4.40 + 3.42 + 2.18).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZnur.png)

Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use SUMIFS inside a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUMIFS($E$1:$E$6,$D$1:$D$6,$B$1:$B$6))*($A$1:$A$6=D10))
```

[image]